# Nginx Make website inaccessible via IP

Tags: nginx, routing, ip

I've got my website set up to be accessible via example.com. If possible I want to prevent it from being  accessed via its IP altogether or at least 301 redirect it to website.

Is the former possible and if yes, how?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Answer (score 10):

You must create a default vhost configuration file and include it before of others.

For example you can save this default config to /etc/nginx/conf/default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 444;
}
```

And include it in nginx.conf:

```
http {
....
 include "/etc/nginx/conf/default.conf";
 include "/etc/nginx/vhosts/*.conf";

}
```

Be sure that it is included before other vhosts' configurations.

Comment: As soon as I include this it is sending 444 when accessed via example.com as well.

Comment: The you are missing proper `server_name` directive from your `example.com` vhost.

Comment: Note that there is no need for a `server_name` directive in the `default_server` server block, and the order files are includes is unimportant given that `default_server` is specified (i.e. `Be sure that it is included before other vhosts' configurations.` <- not necessary).

Comment: No need to specify the IP in the listen directive. Just the port without the leading `:` works fine and makes it bind to all interfaces which is fine unless you have specific needs. For IPv6 the equivalent is `[::]:80`.

Comment: @AD7six:  Thanks for your comment. But on my server, sometimes **default_server** couldn't work fine in nginx. So I suggest placing it before of the others.

Comment: @jasonz then perhaps "sometimes" you forgot to define `default_server` or some similar error =). There'd be little point in having `default_server` if it didn't actually do anything (nginx will only use the first found server block as the default, if there _isn't_ a `default_server` defined). The suggestion by André is for you to improve the answer as specifying the ip is not necessary in most use cases.

Comment: @AD7six: Yes, There'd be little point in having default_server if it didn't actually do anything (nginx will only use the first found server block as the default, if there isn't a default_server defined) => That's right. In my cases, I didn't forget **defautl_server** directive, it didn't work. I don't know what wrong with them. So, I use these configs to be sure that it always works ^^.

Comment: This makes cloudflare return 520 unknown error

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add a server block in your nginx configuration.

The following code will return a 403 error to users accessing your server through the IP :

```
server {
    listen 80; # IPv4
    listen [::]:80; # IPv6 (if enabled)
    server_name ""; # no domain name
    return 403;
}
```

Comment: **That's wrong**. The HTTP/1.1 protocol makes the Host header mandatory and modern browsers send as a value of the Host header the IP address when connecting to it directly, while `""` will match a missing Host header (HTTP/1.0). That's why one should use listen's `default_server` option since you don't need to specify the IP in the `server_name` directive to deny it. The `listen 80` declaration is not necessary (default value of the listen directive). It's also better to use listen's option `ipv6only=false` than two listen directives while accepting both IPv4 and IPv6 in one server block.